# Can anyone else reproduce this bug in the Dart debugger/editor?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

For my sanity, can someone verify a strange bug I'm having with the dart editor?

I'm using the latest dart editor from the main page of the website, I downloaded, extracted, then ran the "DartEditor" executable. (I didn't clear any previous settings that were stored elsewhere, but I don't think that will change the issue.)

```
Dart Editor version 1.0.0_r30798 (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.0.0.10_r30798
```

- Download my repository: https://github.com/Naddiseo/dart-sprintf.git
- Switch to the debugger_ide_test branch
- On console (not in the editor) run `dart test/sprintf_test.dart` The output should be:

  `decimal=1, exp=0, digits=[5, 4, 6, 6]`
- Next, fire up the editor, and open the folder.
- Run the same file, and it should print out the same result.
- Now for the weird part. Set a break point in lib/src/formatters/float_formatter.dart:17 which is the first line of the constructor.
- Run the test file in the editor again then continue once it gets the break point.

With the breakpoint I'm getting the following output:

```
decimal=1, exp=0, digits=[0, 0, 5, 4, 6, 6]
```

I've attributed it to the `List<String>` constructor, which seems to initialise to not be empty.

Does anyone else get this problem? I've tried to condense this into a testable single file, but have failed to reproduce; I'm only able to reproduce it in the actual project.

Comment: How about posting a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely sounds like a bug. As Fox32 suggests, please file a bug on http://dartbug.com/new.

Generally these kind of bugs happen for two reasons:

- The debugger has a side-effect: if the debugger (here the Dart-editor) invokes the actual `toString` method on visible variables, it could have a side-effect. Most commonly this happens to `Iterable`s that have a side-effect.
- The VM has a bug when debugging. The VM has to compile code differently (for example disable some optimizations) to stop at any arbitrary location. It could be that your breakpoint triggers a bug there.

Comment: Those were my suspicions, but I wanted to make sure it wasn't just me that has the issue before I give the dart developers more work to do. But, I'll bug it all the same.

Comment: It looks like it is because my `toString` has side-effects.

Comment: It might be closed as working-as-intended, but I would still file a bug.